# How do I prevent my HTML from being exploitable while avoiding GUIDs?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, security

I've recently inherited a ASP.NET MVC 4 code base. One problem I noted was the use of some database ids (ints) in the urls as well in html form submissions. The code in its present state is exploitable through both URL tinkering and creating custom HTML posts with different numbers.

Now while I can easily fix the URL problems by using session state or additional auth checks i'm less sure about the database ids that get embedded into the HTML that the site spits out (i.e. I give them a drop down to fill). When the ids come back in a post how can I be sure I put them there as valid options?
What is considered "best practice" in terms of addressing this problem?

While I appreciate I could just "GUID it up" I'm hesitant to do so because I find them a pain in the ass to work with when debugging databases.

Do I have a choice here? Must I GUID to prevent easy guessing of ids or is there some kind of DRY mechanism I can use to validate the usage of ids as they come back into the site?

UPDATE: A commenter asked about the exploits I'm expecting. Lets say I spit out a HTML form with a drop down list of all the locations one can import "treasure" from. The id of the locations that the user owns are 1,2 and 3, these are provided in the HTML. But the user examines the html, fiddles with it and decides to put together a POST with the id of 4 selected. 4 is not his location, its someone else's.

Comment: By what mechanism are you expecting exploits? What situation are you in where fiddling the data could compromise your system? Using GUIDs doesn't make anything inherently more secure.

Comment: Updated the OP for you. Guids are more secure in this scenario because you can't guess them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Validate the ID passed against the IDs the user can modify.

It may seem tedious, but this is really the only way to make sure the user has access to what they're trying to modify. Using GUIDs without validation is security by obscurity: sure guessing them is hard, but you can potentially guess them given enough resources.

You can do this at the top of the controller before you do anything else with the posted data. If there's a violation, just throw an exception and have your global exception handler deal with it; you don't need to handle it in a pretty way since you can safely assume that the user is tampering with data in an unsupported way.

Comment: One more edit: _it may see**m** tedious_. ;p -- I was going to do it, but saw you making your own edits and didn't want to collide. ;-)

Comment: So if I get this straight this means that those role attributes that asp.net provides on the API are (design-wise at least) more or less worthless (sure they help a little but they're no silver bullet for auth) as we need to validate most of the users operations ourselves anyway. I say worthless because if one uses them then one is essentially splitting the auth code up between attributes and code at the top of APIs where it would be neater to have all the auth in one place.... I guess what I'm asking is if you still use them.

Comment: @Quibblesome - By `Role` attributes, are you referring to the `Authorize` attribute's Role property? That property is meant to control authorization, i.e. whether or not the user has access to view the specific action/controller -- think more of `Admin` vs. `Regular` user. It's responsibility doesn't extend any further. Validating that the user's actual action/data manipulation is a  question that the business logic can answer, so you must validate the actions yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The issue you describe is known as "insecure direct object references," and the [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org) group recommends two policies for dealing with this issue:

1. using session-based indirect object references, and
2. validating all accesses to object references.

An example of Suggestion #1 would be that instead of having dropdown options 1, 2, and 3, you assign each option a GUID that is associated with the original ID in a map in the user's session. When you get a POST from that user, you check to see what object the given ID was supposed to be tied to. OWASP's ESAPI has some libraries to help with this in various languages.

But in many cases Suggestion #1 is actually counterproductive. For example, in many cases you want to have URLs that can be copy/pasted from one user to another. Process #2 is generally seen as the most foolproof way to address this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing [Broken Access Control](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Broken_Access_Control) with Insecure Ids.  Once you've identified the threat and decided which Ids are owned by certain users, ensure checks are in place for this server side.